# laravel rest api pivot table fetch details array

Tags: laravel

**my controller**

```js
  $PlanSucategory=PlanSucategory::with(['selectCategory'])->get();

        return response()->json($PlanSucategory);
```

**my model**

```js
    protected $orderable = [
        'id',
        'details',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $filterable = [
        'id',
        'select_subcategory.subcategor_name',
        'details',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'details',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function selectSubcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PlanSucategory::class);
    }

    protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
```

**my api response**

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "details": "plan1",
        "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:49",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:49",
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "regular",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "plan_detail_id": "1",
                    "plan_sucategory_id": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "details": "plan2",
        "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:01",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:01",
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "regular",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "plan_detail_id": "2",
                    "plan_sucategory_id": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "details": "plan1",
        "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:11",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:11",
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "subcategor_name": "premium",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:36",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:36",
                "pivot": {
                    "plan_detail_id": "3",
                    "plan_sucategory_id": "2"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "details": "plan3",
        "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:21",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:57:21",
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "subcategor_name": "premium",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:36",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:36",
                "pivot": {
                    "plan_detail_id": "4",
                    "plan_sucategory_id": "2"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "details": "test",
        "created_at": "2022-02-02 08:47:33",
        "updated_at": "2022-02-02 08:47:33",
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "regular",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "pivot": {
                    "plan_detail_id": "5",
                    "plan_sucategory_id": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**i want to show**

```js
        "select_subcategory": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "subcategor_name": "regular",
                "created_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
                "updated_at": "2022-02-02 05:56:24",
               "details":[
               
               "plan1","plan2"
               ]
            }
```

**laravel rest api this line "pivot": {
"plan_detail_id": "2",
"plan_sucategory_id": "1"
}i want to "plan_details_id":[name:"name"] , "plan_sucategory_id":[details:details]

laravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest apilaravel rest api

**

Comment: your question is to dry, there is a bunch of methods how can you get a result, first try to share your controller? and your experience what did you try and why it did not work

Comment: addeded controller and model

Answer (score 0):

you can use in `model` `as('details')`

this is the example:

```
    public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(product::class,'bill_products','bill_id','id_product','id','id')->withPivot('total','quantity_to_bought_by_specefic_user','free')->as('details');
}
```

Comment: "pivot": { "plan_detail_id": "2", "plan_sucategory_id": "1" }i want to "plan_details_id":[name:"name"] , "plan_sucategory_id":[details:details]